# Grep Lines, Sorted By The Pattern Words Order

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Is It Possible to `grep` data based on my words order NOT on order of the input file ?!
for example: Assume That This is my Input file:-

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

Now I want to extract `AAA,CCC,DDD,EEE` ordered as follow:

```
CCC
AAA
EEE
DDD
```

I've tried to use the following command, but ofcourse it didn't work:-

```
$ Grep -rhi "CCC\|AAA\|EEE\|DDD"
$ Grep -hi "CCC\|AAA\|EEE\|DDD" input
AAA
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

Please keep in mind that the data I want to extract, is so much complexed than the example above, as it has some *redirect/pipe/quote* characters in it, and more over, I'm extracting the data from tens (maybe hundreds) of files that almost have the exact same lines' prefixes...
So, the point is there is NoWay at all to use something like `sort` or any similars to sort the lines by any order.

Please tell me If I'm supposed to post any other information.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: You can loop through the words and grep every time. This means doing `grep` so many times, but it is still valid: `for pattern in CCC AAA EEE DDD; do grep "$pattern" input; done`. Or better, just `grep` normally and then take the patterns into account to sort: you can loop through these patterns and grep the output file.

Comment: in your input file, each line has one word, and in your pattern, the words you want to search are exactly same as those lines in input file? If it is true, there could be shortcut.

Comment: you need two stages, first "find" then "sort", which is what the perl based answer from @Birei does

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), parsing input string and save entries in an array, then parse the input file and save each line as a key of a hash, so now you can traverse the array and only print the line that matches the hash, like:

```
perl -e '
    @input = split /\\\|/, shift;
    open $fh, "<", shift;
    while ( $line = <$fh> ) {
        $line =~ s/\A\s+//; $line =~ s/\s+$//;
        $file{ $line } = 1;
    }
    for $i ( @input ) {
        if ( exists $file{ $i } ) { printf "%s\n", $i; };
    }
' "CCC\|AAA\|EEE\|DDD" infile
```

It yields:

```
CCC
AAA
EEE
DDD
```